# Conditional formatting for passed dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I need the formula to highlight a cell if the date in that cell has passed. 
Cell U3 had 6/29/19 today is 7/1/19 - I want to have the cell turn red after 6/29 to alert me to follow up.

Answer (score 0):

- select desired range
- select **Date is before**
- and select **today**

  [image: 0]